# A Theory that has as Models exactly the Reducts of another Theory

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am working through the book "Model Theory" by Chang and Keisler at the moment. Now I am stuck at exercise 2.2.18 which states:

"Let $\mathcal{L}'$ be an expansion of $\mathcal{L}$ and let $T'$ be a theory in $\mathcal{L}'$. Suppose that each model $\mathfrak{A}$ for $\mathcal{L}$ has at most one expansion to a model $T'$. Prove that there is a theory $T$ in $\mathcal{L}$ such that the models of $T$ are exactly the reducts of the models of $T'$ to $\mathcal{L}$."

By a model $\mathfrak{A}$ for $\mathcal{L}$ they mean an $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathfrak{A}$.

It is clear to me that, if some theory $T$ does it, then it must be the theory $T$ of all consequences of $T'$ which are equivalent to an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence. Every reduct $\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathcal{L}$ of a model of $T'$ clearly satisfies this $T$. Moreover it is somehow the biggest theory with this property, because if we add some $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\varphi$ to $T$, it will not be a consequence of $T'$, so there will be some model $\mathfrak{A}'$ of $T'$ not satisfying $\varphi$. In particular the reduct $\mathfrak{A}$ of $\mathfrak{A}'$ to $\mathcal{L}$ will not satisfy $\varphi$.

Now my next step would be taking an $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathfrak{B}$ not satisfying $T$ and showing that it cannot be a reduct of a model of $T'$. But I have no idea how it shall help me that $\mathfrak{B}$ can have at most one expansion to a model of $T'$.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You mean "Suppose that each model $\mathfrak{A}$ for $\mathcal{L}$ has at most one expansion to a model **of** $T'$." right?

Comment: That is a mistake which the authors made, so I did not correct it. But for sure it should be like you wrote it.

Comment: I think we also have to prove that any model of $T$ does have an expansion that satisfies $T'$.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you!

Comment: Hint: The assumption "each model $\mathfrak{A}$ for $\mathcal{L}$ has at most one expansion to a model of $T'$" is crucial here. You'll want to use the Beth definability theorem (or rather, it's immediate consequence Exercise 2.2.17).

Comment: Thank you! I should have thought about using the exercise I just did before...

Comment: @DanielW. I still don't get the solution. What is 2.2.17 saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be another way to prove this statement : try to show that the class $\mathcal{R}$ consisting of all the $\mathcal{L}$-reducts of models of $T'$ is an elementary class. For this, we need to show that this class is closed under $\rlap{\mathcal{L}}{\rule[2.5pt]{5pt}{0.5pt}}$-<s>isomorphisms</s> **elementary substructure** and under ultraproducts.

> $\mathcal{R}$ is closed under ultraproducts.

Let $(\mathfrak{A}_i)_{i\in I}$ be a familly of elements of $\mathcal{R}$, and $\mathcal{U}$ be an ultrafilter of parts of $I$. For each $i \in I$, let $\mathfrak{A}'_i$ be the unique expansion of $\mathfrak{A}_i$ to a model of $T'$. The ultraproduct $\prod_\mathcal{U} \mathfrak{A}_i$ is a reduct of $\prod_\mathcal{U} \mathfrak{A}'_i$.

Comment: The class should be closed under ultraproducts and *elementary equivalence*, no?

Comment: @Berci Thanks, that's where I made a mistake indeed! I have to edit that...